# Update namespace of xml column

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml

After refactoring I found that its needed to change namespace of existing data. Each db row contains column with data like:

```
<Bla xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.contoso.com/ooo/entities/v1">
   <Titles>
      <smth sourceId="19" targetId="2">
         <smth2>New</smth2>
      </smth>
   </Titles>
</Bla>
```

How to update value `xmlns="http://schemas.contoso.com/ooo/entities/v1"` to be `xmlns="http://schemas.contoso.com/ooo/common/v1"`

Actual exception is `InvalidOperationException` (namespace was not expected). m.b it's possible to change data reader deserialization but...

Answer (score 0):

```sql
update MyTable
set MyColumn = 
Convert(xml,
    REPLACE(
        Convert(nvarchar(max), MyColumn),
        'http://schemas.contoso.com/ooo/entities/v1',
        'http://schemas.contoso.com/ooo/common/v1')
    )
```